# React / WebPack - Lazy Loading - Random CSS Chunk Load Errors

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, deployment, lazy-loading

I'm currently having a problem in our React / Webpack Deployment Build. We are trying to lazy import our different Pages due to performance optimization.

Upon lazy importing the components / pages I recieve random CSS Chunk load errors. It's really hard to reproduce because it seems to appear randomly. On some page reloads it loads the chunks as intended and sometimes i get this error.

I'm currently using react rewired to override webpack configs, which looks like this:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.output = {
        ...config.output, // copy all settings
        filename: "static/js/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
        publicPath: 'auto',
    };
    config.optimization = {
        ...config.optimization,
    }
    console.log(config);
    return config;
};
```

[image: Chunk Error]

When I'm trying to access the chunk file in another tab I always recieve it so it has to be there.

It's also interesting that it's ALWAYS the CSS Chunk which fails to load, no problems with the JS Chunks. (Or is it only the first chunk which are loaded, and the other chunks would fail to ? )

[image: Network Error]

I tried lazy importing the pages with [lazy](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy) and also with a "self built" lazy import. (Promises from imports)

The error occurs in both cases.

Do you have any ideas, what could be the cause of this issue and how to fix it ? Thanks in advance